# Using ViewBag with Html.DropDownList getting Cast error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to use `ViewBag` to populate a `Html.DropDownList` method but when I do I get the error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType0`2[System.Int16,System.String]]' to type 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList'.

I am sure this is due to using an `AnyonymousType` when filling the `ViewBage` but I am not sure how to setup the `ViewBag` as a `SelectList`

`using (CoreSiteContext db = new CoreSiteContext())
{
    ViewBag.Sections = db.Sections
                            .Select(s => new { s.ID, s.Title })
                            .ToList();
}`

`@Html.DropDownList("Sections", (SelectList) ViewBag.Sections, "--Select Section--")`

How exactly should I be setting up my ViewBag to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `SelectList` wrong - you are trying to cast your anonymous type to a `SelectList`, which wont work. Here is the correct usage:

```
using (CoreSiteContext db = new CoreSiteContext())
{
    var items = db.Sections
                  .Select(s => new { s.ID, s.Title })
                  .ToList();

    var selectList = new SelectList(items, "ID", "Title");
    ViewBag.Sections = selectList;
}
```

Comment: How do you then pass that `SelectList` up since your not assigning it to `ViewBag`?

Comment: Added an extra line to add select list to `ViewBag`

Comment: glad to help! don't forget to mark as answer as correct answer if it indeed is.

Comment: @CamBruce Just did, had to wait for the time list to pass before I could.